# Function comparing list with a number

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I am pretty new in python and programming in general and i need help. i need to write a function which compares a given list with an integer. In the end the function count how many times the number is bigger than the elements in the list. It also should not consider negativ numbers. I wrote a code but it doesnt give me the rigth answer:

```py
def count_smaller(input_list: List[int], compared_number: int) -> int:
    a = -1
    for i in input_list:
        if compared_number <= 0:
            continue
        elif compared_number > i:
            a += 1
            return a
        else:
            a = 0
            return a

c = count_smaller([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3], 2)
print(c)
```

this code gives me a 1 but the obvious answer is 2. I am really struggling with this task and i hope someone can help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where does `compared_number` come from and what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are a couple of problems in your code:

- First of all, the declaration of `a = -1` is completely useless (did you think to something in particular declaring it that way?).
- Then, with all those `returns` you are going to verify only the fist non negative number and than return your result.
- Last but not least, you are incrementing the couter if che number is lower than `compared_number` here `compared_number > i`.

This should work:

```
def count_smaller(input_list, compared_number):
    a = 0
    for i in input_list:
        if compared_number <= 0:
            continue
        elif compared_number <= i:
            a += 1
    return a


c = count_smaller([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3], 2)
print(c)
```

The output will be:

```
2
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I was a little bit confused with return but i can see my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a list comprehension:

```
def count_smaller(input_list, compared_number):
    return sum(
        [1 for item in input_list if item >= 0 and compared_number > item]
    )


c = count_smaller([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3], 2)
print(c)
```

Out:

```
2
```